# Firebug FireDiff - how to save entire CSS file?

Tags: css, firebug

I'm modifying CSS using Firebug and FireDiff. I've had a couple of 'accidents' where I have 'saved a snapshot' but in fact just saved a diff (one or two changes), uploaded it to my web server and overwrote the full CSS file with a snippet. Fortunately I have been making periodic backups.

Question: how do I ensure that I save the whole file - either using Firebug itself or FireDiff?

Answer (score 0):

## Firebug

With Firebug itself you can save the CSS following these steps:

1. After you've made your changes switch to the [*CSS* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel)
2. Select the modified CSS file from the [CSS Location Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel#CSS_Location_Menu)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole CSS and copy it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or by right-clicking on the selection and choosing *Copy* from the context menu
4. Paste the CSS into the text editor of your choice and save it

## FireDiff

With FireDiff the steps are a bit different:

1. After you've made your changes switch to the *Changes* panel
2. Within the change log right-click on the CSS change you've made to the file you want to save and choose *Save Snapshot* from the context menu
   [image: Save snapshot option in FireDiff]
3. Enter a file name into the save dialog and save the it

**Notes:**
FireDiff requires another extension called [Fireformat](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/fireformat/?src=stackoverflow) to save snapshots.

As the word 'snapshot' indicates FireDiff saves the file including all changes up to the one you've chosen. If you want to save the current state of a file, you need to choose the last change to that file.

For both methods you need to take care in which file the CSS was saved. In case of inline CSS, i.e. CSS included in the HTML output via the `<style>` tag you need to save the CSS back to the HTML output.

## Other extensions

Besides doing this in Firebug or using FireDiff there are [Firebug extensions](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions), which claim to allow you to upload your changes directly to your server via FTP. These extensions are [cssUpdater](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#cssUpdater) and [FireFile](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#FireFile). Though they seem to not be maintained anymore and may not work with current versions of Firebug.

Comment: thank you for your detailed reply. That's the way I expect it to work but not what I experience.
I have just added a new rule `#tagline` and it is rendered correctly on the browser. When I go to Firebug it doesn't appear in the modified CSS file window. If I copy and paste I lose the edit. 
FireDiff doesn't behave as expected either. Right-click on most recent edit, selecting Save Snapshot is resulting in saving a diff.
FireFox 33. Firebug 2.0.6. FireDiff 1.2.1. Windows XP.

Comment: cssUpdater and FireFile seem unreliable too. Sometimes they work. Sometimes they start the operation but seem to have an FTP problem and I end up with a 0 byte file on my server. There is no confirmation that synch was successful.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: Please add the exact steps you did to your question, then it's easier to reproduce your problem. Note that when you add a rule within the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel) it's added to a **new** inline style sheet. Also, copy & paste should not lose the edit. Saving as snapshot saves the whole file for me. To your second comment: I have to admit I didn't try these extensions out myself yet. If you think they are buggy, you should report that to their authors.

Comment: I tried to install cssUpdater and FireFile now and didn't get them to run. So I updated the my answer covering this.